# Remove grey background without removing gridlines

Tags: r, ggplot2, background, themes, gridlines

Is there a way to remove the grey background from a ggplot graph, without removing the gridlines and without using `theme_bw()`?

Comment: [Change the colors of the plot panel background and the grid lines](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-themes-and-background-colors-the-3-elements)

Comment: is there a particular reason you *don't* want to use `theme_bw()` ?

Answer (score 6):

As the default ggplot theme (`theme_grey`) has a "white" color for the grid lines you have to set a different color for the grid lines when removing the grey background, i.e. when setting the `fill` for the background to "white" or `NA`. In the code below I simply use black grid lines:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_line(color = "black"))
```

[image]